# Resolution when connecting to a headless Mac Mini

Tags: display, mac-mini, remote-desktop, resolution, headless

My setup is as follows:

1. Mac Mini 2012 with a [dummy video adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FLZXGJ6) with latest OSX.
2. Retina Macbook Pro 13-inch, Early 2015 running the default OSX VNC client with the latest OSX.
3. [Display Menu](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12) to switch resolutions.

My problem is that I'm not able to get the right resolution such that it fills up the entire Retina Macbook Pro display. Ideally I would have liked 1280x800 or equivalent higher. This way it would fill up the entire screen (though it would be scaled since Retina has a higher resolution, which is fine).

However the only resolution options I see are:

[image: Resolution options]

My question is that do these options depend on the dummy video adapter? If so, is there a recommended video adapter to achieve such a setup?

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure how you could do this within macOS, but I know that every portable Mac I’ve owned since the PowerBook G4, as well as my current Mac mini, all run a tool called SwitchResX. It has saved me so many times in connecting to projectors, screens, etc. and in exactly the same situation you’re in where I wanted to have my MacBook Air screen resolution exactly matched by the Mac mini so that I had a full screen experience.

Go and have a look at SwitchResX over at http://www.madrau.com. There is a fully functional 10-day trial version, and €14 buys you a license. Well-worth the expense in my opinion!

Answer (score 0):

That video adapter only supports resolutions up to 1080p. You would need one that supports 4K resolutions, [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JKFTYA8).

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I think my problem is that it doesn't show a resolution with 16:10 aspect ratio (which would fill up my Macbook Pros display edge to edge)